# Copy multiple new files loaded from SFTP server to Azure Blob Storage using SFTP-ssh connector

Tags: azure, azure-functions, sftp, azure-logic-apps

I have to copy each new files copied in SFTP server into Azure Blob storage. I have created the Logic app when a blob is added or modified with sftp-ssh properties since I have to read larger files of size 500MB. Each new files triggered copying into Azure storage. This is working fine when I add single file in SFTP server. However, when I drop multiple files in SFTP server, the files are failing with error

```
{ "status": 404, "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist.\r\nclientRequestId: 7a23df8-31be-43f4-8153-aaadcvfg5f1e", "error": { "message": "The provided path '/abc/Test/file1.txt' does not exist." }
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3HsE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37RnG.png)

Comment: what are the details of the "Get file content" connector?

Comment: Attached the details of  getfile content and get file content settings

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? i have the same question